# Ruby on Rails - jQuery events not working properly

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails

I am migrating a front-end project to rails. I have two routes, /home and /home/new. The /home view has a link to go to the /home/new view. If I manually, enter the route on the address bar, everything renders perfectly. If I go the the view via the link on the /home view, the jQuery events don't function properly, leading to the styles dependent on them not working properly. There are no errors in the console. Can anyone help me?

Link to github repository:  https://github.com/rimildeyjsr/sms-scheduler

This is how the styles should get rendered:

[image]

This us how it's getting rendered, when visited via the link:

[image]

application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>SmsScheduler</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:regular,bold,italic,thin,light,bolditalic,black,medium&amp;lang=en" %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Mono" %>


  </head>

  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

assets.rb :

```
# Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file.

# Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets.
Rails.application.config.assets.version = '1.0'
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( mdDateTimePicker.css )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( style.css )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( mdDateTimePicker.js )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( app.js )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( home.style.css )
# Add additional assets to the asset load path
# Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Emoji.images_path

# Precompile additional assets.
# application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS in app/assets folder are already added.
# Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( search.js )
```

application.css

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or any plugin's vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any other CSS/SCSS
 * files in this directory. Styles in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
 * It is generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require jquery-ui
 *= require material
 *= require mdDateTimePicker
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */
```

application.js

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or any plugin's vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file. JavaScript code in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/rails/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require material
//= require moment
//= require draggabilly.pkgd
//= require mdDateTimePicker
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  get '/home', to: 'home#index'
  get '/home/new', to: 'home#new'
end
```

app.js

```
ready = function(){
    $('.mdl-card__supporting-text').hide();
    var animationEnd = 'webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend';
    $('#fab').click(function(){

        var innerHtml = $('#fab .material-icons').html();
        if (innerHtml === 'add'){
            console.log(2);
            $('#fab').css('background-color','green');
            $('#fab .material-icons').html('check circle');
            $('.mdl-card__supporting-text').show();
            $('.mdl-card__title').hide();
        }

        else {
            $('.mdl-card__supporting-text').hide();
            $('#fab').css('background-color','#ed2553');
            $('#fab .material-icons').html('add');
            $('.mdl-card__title').show();
            $('#title-text').text('Campaign added!');
        }

    });

    $('#sms-msg').keyup(function(){
        var Length = $('#sms-msg').val().length;
        var pageBreak = Math.floor((Length/160));
        $('#break-msg').val(pageBreak+1);
    });

    var inputStartDate = document.querySelector('#start-date');
    var outputStartDate = document.querySelector('#start-date-label');

    var inputEndDate = document.querySelector('#end-date');
    var outputEndDate = document.querySelector('#end-date-label');

    var inputStartTime = document.querySelector('#start-time');
    var outputStartTime = document.querySelector('#start-time-label');


    var dialogStartDate = new mdDateTimePicker.default({
        type: 'date',
        orientation: 'PORTRAIT',
        past: moment().subtract(150,'years'),
        future: moment().add(50,'years')
    });

    dialogStartDate.trigger = inputStartDate;

    if (inputStartDate) {
        inputStartDate.addEventListener('click', function() {
            dialogStartDate.toggle();
            $('.container-div').toggle();
        });

        inputStartDate.addEventListener('onOk', function() {
            var startDate = dialogStartDate.time.toString();
            var startDateFormat = moment(startDate).format('LL');
            outputStartDate.innerHTML = startDateFormat;
            $('#start-date-label').css('color','blue');
            $('.container-div').show();
        });

        inputStartDate.addEventListener('onCancel',function(){
            $('.container-div').show();
        });
    }




    var dialogEndDate = new mdDateTimePicker.default({
        type: 'date',
        orientation: 'PORTRAIT',
        past: moment().subtract(150,'years'),
        future: moment().add(150,'years')
    });

    dialogEndDate.trigger = inputEndDate;

    if (inputEndDate) {
        inputEndDate.addEventListener('click', function() {
            dialogEndDate.toggle();
            $('.container-div').toggle();
        });

        inputEndDate.addEventListener('onOk', function() {
            var endDate = dialogEndDate.time.toString();
            var endDateFormat = moment(endDate).format('LL');
            outputEndDate.innerHTML = endDateFormat;
            $('#end-date-label').css('color','blue');
            $('.container-div').show();
        });

        inputEndDate.addEventListener('onCancel',function(){
            $('.container-div').show();
        });
    }



    var dialogStartTime = new mdDateTimePicker.default({
        type: 'time',
        orientation: 'PORTRAIT',
    });

    dialogStartTime.trigger = inputStartTime;

    if (inputStartTime) {
        inputStartTime.addEventListener('click', function() {
            dialogStartTime.toggle();
            $('.container-div').toggle();
        });

        inputStartTime.addEventListener('onOk', function() {
            $('.container-div').show();
            var startTime = dialogStartTime.time.toString();
            var startTimeFormat = moment(startTime).format('LTS');
            outputStartTime.innerHTML = startTimeFormat;
            $('#start-time-label').css('color','blue');
        });

        inputStartTime.addEventListener('onCancel',function(){
            $('.container-div').show();
        });
    }



}

$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on("page:change", ready);
```

Comment: Are you using Rails 5?

Comment: For Rails 5 (turbolinks 5), use `$(document).on("turbolinks:load", ready);` instead of `$(document).on("page:change", ready);`.

Comment: Some styles are rendering now, others aren't :(

Comment: @31piy - precisely my floating labels from material design lite in my form is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that removing turbolinks from the project, completely solves the problem!

remove gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5' from the Gemfile.

remove //= require turbolinks from your application.js

Application.html.erb

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your mdDateTimePicker file/files that are missing/not loading located in your project directory? It's not included in the github repo.

Comment: i have added it to vendor/assets in the respective javascript and stylesheet folder

Comment: the scripts are all loading perfectly

Comment: Can you call a function in the console successfully from one of the scripts? This seems like it's a turbo-links issue, tbh.